# Search not updating after moving managed metadata term under new parent term

Tags: 2013, search, managed-metadata

I have issue where moving metadata term isn't reflected to search.

1. I have simple hierarchy of metadata with two parent terms A and B, and A has one child term C.
2. On some SharePoint list item with managed metadata field called MyCategory, I assign C as the metadata value.
3. Run full crawl
4. Search for items containing the term, e.g., `k=owstaxIdMyCategory:[GUID]` where [GUID] represents ID of term A --> I get all items tagged with term A and term C
5. I move term C under B
6. Run full crawl
7. Run Taxonomy Update Scheduler timer job
8. Search for items containing the term, e.g., `k=owstaxIdMyCategory:[GUID]` where [GUID] represents ID of term B --> I get all items tagged with term B but not the item tagged with term C
9. BONUS: Search for items containing the term, e.g., `k=owstaxIdMyCategory:[GUID]` where [GUID] represents ID of term A --> I get all items tagged with term A and still the item tagged with term C

How to reflect this change in managed metadata term structure in search as full crawl and running Taxonomy Update Scheduler don't help?

Answer (score 0):

Running Index Reset seems to do the trick. Feel free to comment if you know lighter way.